# Qual e a diferença do @import do css e do Link do html?

Tags: html, css

Criei um arquivo contendo padrões de `css` que são usados no meu sistema.
Gostaria de saber qual e a diferença entre chamar o css pelo `link` ou pelo `@import` assim:

```css
/* ou dentro do codEventos.css */

@import "../padrao.css";
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="padrao.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="codEventos.css">
```

Quais são as vantagens/desvantagens?

Li em um link: [dont-use-import](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/)
que há uma grande diferença em desempenho, visto que o `link` consegue carregar o `css` em paralelo fazendo ter mais desempenho sobre o `@import`,claro não são todos os browsers que intepretam assim.

Comment: Não tenho como detalhar uma resposta no momento, mas se eu não estiver enganado `<link>` vai trabalhar em uma base do path da página que a chamou e o `@import` pode trabalhar bem diferente, ou seja haverá em "alguns casos" diferenças no uso de url()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Na teoria, a única diferença entre eles é que @import é o mecanismo
>   CSS para incluir uma folha de estilos e `<link>` é o mecanismo HTML
>   para fazer o mesmo. Contudo, cada browser as manipula de formas
>   diferentes, dando ao `<link>` uma clara vantagem em termos de
>   performance.
>
> Steve Sourders escreveu um extenso artigo em seu blog, comparando o
>   impacto de ambos `<link>` e @import (e todas as possíveis combinações
>   entre eles) chamado ["don't use @import"](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/) ("Não use @import"). O
>   título já diz tudo.
>
> Yahoo! também o menciona como uma de suas melhores escolhas de
>   performance (em co-autoria com Steve Sourders): [Choose `<link>` over
>   @import](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#csslink). ("Escolha `<link>` em vez de @import").
>
> Além disso, usar a tag `<link>` permite a você definir páginas de
>   estilo "preferidas" e alternativas. Você não pode fazer isso com
>   @import.

***Esta é uma tradução na íntegra da resposta em inglês para essa mesma pergunta, a qual se encontra em https://stackoverflow.com/a/1022715/1639385***

Comment: Boa resposta! #UlyssesAlves +1

Comment: Obrigado, @AlíciaTairini Mas os créditos na verdade são do [mercator](http://stackoverflow.com/users/23263/mercator), autor da resposta original em inglês ;)

Answer (score 0):

Não existe diferenças basicamente, o **link** é o método do html de chamar um stylesheet, o **@import** o do css.

No entanto, os browser interpretam eles de uma maneira diferente, onde o **link** tem vantagem em termos de performance.

Caso entenda inglês confira essa reposta : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022695/difference-between-import-and-link-in-css

Abraço